# How to enable special characters "&#9760;" in PHP?

Tags: php, html, unicode, html-entities

My old page in linux worked perfectly, but when I try to change the server from Unix to Windows characters no longer work.
My old skull character "☠" "9760" is shown in box with hex definitions 26 and 20.

Comment: This has to do with certain fonts not being able to display all Unicode characters or browser configured incorrectly. http://unicode.org/help/display_problems.html

Comment: The "2620" is a reference to the skull and crossbones character you're trying to use with `&#9760;`. Did you change anything else, like the font for the page, or the computer/browser you're using to visit the page?

Comment: How was the file effected by the change?  Was the encoding changed to, for example, ANSI?

Comment: Oh rely the Unix fonts like "Helvetica" and "Sans-Serif" i just not have in my XP. by adding this everything is working good. THank you so much guys!!!

Comment: @Tedy, post an answer with something like, *"I was missing fonts X and Y, when they're added to the system, everything works"*, and accept it.  It lets others know the question is solved.

Answer (score 2):

The box with 26 and 20 indicates lack of glyphs for the character U+2620 (decimal code 9760). This is one of the recommended ways of [dealing with undisplayable characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.4) according to the HTML 4.01 spec. So it indicates that the character has been properly recognized by the browser, it just cannot display it.

It sounds very odd that the OS of the *server* would affect this. It would be interesting to see the URLs of two versions that demonstrate such an effect. But changing *browser* or *client computer* may surely have an effect.

This is not entirely a browser problem, though. “Undisplayable” is relative, because browsers (especially IE) may fail to render a character, even though there *is* a glyph for it in available fonts. Therefore, you may wish to use a `font-family` setting with a suitable list of alternatives; to check out font coverage, see
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2620/fontsupport.htm